# Magento Ajax cart remove items not working in mini cart

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, addtocart

I have created the custom ajax cart in magento,in that mini cart is updated without loading the page.But in that remove items link is not working,it is been redirecting to ajaxDelete action url(for eg:

http://dev.magento.com/index.php/checkout/cart/ajaxDelete/id/19/uenc/aHR0cDovL2Rldi5tYWdlbnRvLmNvbS9pbmRleC5waHAvdGVzdC5odG1s/).

Its not showing the confirm box.Code I have used for mini cart in controller is,

```
$mini_cart              = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('minicart_head');
$response['minicart']   = $mini_cart->toHtml();
```

in list.phtml I used,

```
if (jQuery('.header-minicart')){
        jQuery('.header-minicart').html( data.minicart );
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This may be form key issue.In `ajaxDeleteAction()` function,magento is check form key using below code:

```
   if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        Mage::throwException('Invalid form key');
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your comment.ok How can I rectify this issue.

Comment: @Sree not sure if you found the solution yet, but you need to send the form key in the URL to fix this issue.

Comment: @Sree - did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: @amit - is there any workaround for this issue ?

Comment: I will  late you  know  at night